# Connect facebook Webhook with asp.net application

Tags: .net, facebook, callbackurl

I am trying to connect facebook webhook to asp.net application but I am getting 'The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge' error.

However I can see the response is correct from my .net application but in facebook it shows with prefix '\ufeff\'
[Here is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T99fs.png)

I am sending response to callback url using below code :

```
        var challenge = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["hub.challenge"]);

        var verifyToken = Request.QueryString["hub.verify_token"];


        if (verifyToken == "abcxyz123")
        {

            Response.Write(challenge);
        }
```

Any help is greatly apprecialted.
Thanks

Comment: That’s a BOM, Byte Order Mark. Remove the BOM from your script files, store them as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: I used new UTF8Encoding(false) to remove BOM from .net application, But this Byte Order Mark is added by PHP when response is being captured by Callback url initated by Facebook.
I checked the string it is without BOM.

Comment: What, where does PHP come into play here?

Comment: We have to set callback url and access token in Facebook.Facebook sends https request to my application.On request above code is executed and facebook receives the string returned in above code 
 : Resonse.write(challenge).

Screen shot attached in question is getting on facebook while connecting webhook to my application.

I am referring this link :  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/quickstart/webhooks-integration

Only thing is I want to connect to asp.net application but here it is given in PHP.

Comment: Ok, so their example is in PHP ... but what does that have to do with _your_ app?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Webhook()
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["hub.challenge"])
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

        return response;
    }
```